# Optimizing Flink's memory usage

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I meet a scenario to deploy Flink on some IoT devices, so what I concern about is the limited resources on these platforms, the default configuration results in unacceptable memory usage to me. I'm trying to modify the memory configuration(of taskmanager) in `flink-conf.yaml` according to official docs and some blogs.
Here are what I found and was confused:

- If I set the `Task Heap` to 0 the jobs can still run normally, and results through operators still remain correct. Are  `Task Heap` and `Framework Heap` shared so the tasks can utilize heap memory other than `Task Heap`?
- I also set the `Managed Memory` to 0 since I'm not using RocksDB as state backend, so the intermediate states should be stored on the heap memory. I found an interesting thing here: the size of `Task Heap` configured in `flink-conf.yaml` is related to the runtime memory usage of taskmanager. For example, by default it's set to 256MB, when a job is running the memory usage of taskmanager can be up to 800MB. When I set it to a small number instead, like 10MB, memory usage of taskmanager would be at most 500MB. And from the Flink UI I noticed that JVM would run GC much more frequently when `Task Heap` is small. I can't find corresponding explain from Flink's docs. I guess there is a space to store states somewhere on the heap, the space size is related to `Task Heap`, and every time it's fullfilled the JVM will call GC.
- About the metrics shown on Flink UI, the part of `Network` is reflected in real memory occupation even though it's "not actually used". For example, if `Network` is set to 100MB, taskmanager will take 90MB more memory compared to when it's set to 10MB, but most of time the usage of  `Network` is less than 1MB.
- I'm also wondering whether the memory occupied by taskmanager, as a JVM process, is exactly or approximatively equal to `Heap` + `Non-Heap` + `Outside JVM Memory`? When there is no job running I think it's reasonable, but after a job is submitted, taskmanager will occupy a few hundred MBs more memory but I can's find corresponding terms on Flink UI.

Many thanks if you can explain my problems above.

Comment: What version of Flink are you using for these experiments?

Comment: version 1.16, and Flink is deployed via Docker